Changing a single line in my code leads to an infinite loop
In the following code,
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector <int> otm;
vector <int> past;
vector <int> strength;

bool leaves(int n){
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if (otm[i] == 1 && past[i] == 0 && strength[i] < strength[0]){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    otm.resize(n, 1);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        int a;
        cin >> a;
        strength.push_back(a);
    }
    
    int prep[n];
    past.resize(n, 0);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i ++){
        int a;
        int b;
        cin >> a >> b;
        prep[b - 1] = a - 1;
        past[a - 1]++;

    }
    
    while (leaves(n)){
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            if (otm[i] == 1 && past[i] == 0 && strength[i] < strength[0]){ //this is 48 line
                otm[i] = 0;
                past[prep[i]]--;
            }
        }
    }
    
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if (otm[i] == 1){
            sum++;
        }
    }
    cout << sum - 1;
}

changing line 48 to:
if (otm[i] == 1 && past[i] == 0 && strength[i] > strength[0]){
like its supposed to be, it goes into an infinite loop. Any ideas as to why it leads to an infinite loop?

int prep[n]; -- This is not valid C++.  Arrays in C++ must have their size denoted by a compile-time expression, not a runtime variable.  You are already using std::vector, so why didn't you use it here?  --> std::vector<int> prep(n);

We're humans, not a compiler. Some explanation of what your code is trying to do, and why you think it should say strength[i] > strength[0], will go a long way toward helping us understand your problem!

It must be causing leaves(n) to return true all the time.

Did you try stepping through it in a debugger, or otherwise checking on how the performance disagrees with your mental model?

Changing that if condition changes whether otm[i] and past[prep[i]] are updated. That will affect the condition in leaves().

like its supposed to be -- If the program misbehaves, then it isn't "supposed to be".  The next step is for you to debug your code to determine where and how to fix the code.

apparently the code is not doing what you think it should be doing, so step through it in a debugger and find the bug, that's what debuggers are for

Aside: global variables are generally advised against.

Does this answer your question? What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?

Compare the logic inside leaves() to the logic inside the while loop in question.  Let's walk through the logic:

main() reaches leaves() for the 1st time.  To enter the while loop body, leaves() must return true, meaning it found a match where otm[i] == 1 and past[i] == 0 and strength[i] < strength[0] are all true.

OK, so let's assume leaves() finds a match and returns true and the while loop body is thus entered.

In the original code that IS NOT infinite, the while loop body performs the exact same checks that leaves() has already performed.  So the while loop body is guaranteed to update at least 1 item in the otm[] and past[] arrays, for the match that leaves() found (maybe more items, since you don't break the inner loop after an update). Since there is a guaranteed update of the otm[] array on every iteration of the while loop, leaves() will eventually run out of matching items in the otm[] array and return false, breaking the while loop.

In the modified code that IS infinite, the while loop body checks the values of the strength[] array differently than how leaves() checks them.  So, it is possible for leaves() to find a match and return true, but then for the while loop to subsequently not find any match, thus skipping its update of the otm[] and past[] arrays.  And once this situation happens, the next time leaves() is called again, the values it checks have not changed, so it returns true again, and the values the while loop body checks have not changed either, so it skips the updates again, and the while loop continues on, doing the same thing over and over, not changing anything, forever.




So, to avoid this situation, you have to make sure that leaves() and the while loop agree on the conditions that they check.  But you are performing those checks in two different places, so you risk modifying one and forgetting to modify the other.  You should refactor the code to prevent that, eg:
bool do_check(int i){
    return (otm[i] == 1 && past[i] == 0 && strength[i] < strength[0]);
}

bool leaves(int n){
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if (do_check(i)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

...

while (leaves(n)){
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if (do_check(i)) {
            otm[i] = 0;
            past[prep[i]]--;
        }
    }
}

Otherwise, just get rid of leaves(), as it is redundant in this code, eg:
int main()
{
    ...

    bool updated;
    do {
        updated = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            if (otm[i] == 1 && past[i] == 0 && strength[i] < strength[0]){
                otm[i] = 0;
                past[prep[i]]--;
                updated = true;
            }
        }
    }
    while (updated);

    ...
}

